# Another one question about this - Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo

Tags: java, maven, gwt, pom.xml

Has anyone encountered an error
`Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo`?
I know that there is a topic about this error, but I have already tried all the ways and solutions, but nothing comes out. Please tell me how to compile a GWT project for IntelliJ IDEA.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images..post the text..furthermore much more details...which Maven version do you use? A good reason why not using most recent version https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/ ???

Comment: @khmarbaise maven version is 3.8.6. I can't choose a version higher than 3.0.0 for this plugin.